# Does Google index private WordPress pages?

Tags: wordpress, google-search, google-index

I have a customer claiming that a page that is marked as private under WordPress showed up on Google search.

The page showed up on Google search, but when the user reached the page, it returned a 404 not found (as it should).

Is this possible?

Comment: It's unlikely, but not really possible to provide a blanket statement that Google 100% wouldn't be able to access pages marked as "Private" - considering the wide array of functionality the WP plugin/theme engine can provide, it's certainly possible the content of this page is exposed (inadvertently or otherwise) by a third-party plugin or theme.

Comment: I just thought of something.  Could an out of date sitemap with that page included allow google to index the page?

Comment: Certainly - from [Google's own docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en): "*Search engines like Google read [your sitemap] to more intelligently crawl your site. A sitemap tells the crawler which files you think are important in your site, and also provides valuable information about these files...*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something (a theme, plugin, etc) has changed how that installation of WordPress works, a page published as private should not be viewable unless the visitor is logged in as editor or admin, as per the WordPress docs:

> Private content is published only for your eyes, or the eyes of only those with authorization permission levels to see private content. Normal users and visitors will not be aware of private content. It will not appear in the article lists. If a visitor were to guess the URL for your private post, they would still not be able to see your content. You will only see the private content when you are logged into your WordPress blog. ... Private posts are automatically published but not visible to anyone but those with the appropriate permission levels (Editor or Administrator).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content

If you can view the page without being logged in as editor/admin, then Google can see it too, and you'd need to check the theme/plugins to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Just had another thought, in case it helps: If the page was once public and now the customer has changed it to private, it may still be listed in Google search results. If so, try requesting removal: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Google can index pages set to private, even if it returns 404 when not logged in. I'm looking at it right now on my site, and I'm confused.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).